# How can this function run?

Tags: javascript, function

```js
function show() {
  return value;
}

let value = 1000


console.log(show());
```

I guess let is the local variable but I don't understand why this coding returns 1000

I thought an message would appear

> value is not defined

Comment: Because your `value` variable and `show()` function are in the same scope

Answer (score -1):

The problem here, is that the variable is declared in the global scope, so regardless of using let it becomes global.

You can use let insisde a block, and that binding then will be visible only inside the block.

See this for further info:
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_let.asp